# one point subtree crossover using python ast

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, genetic-programming

Currently, We are working with ast representation of python program in Genetic Programming and we are not able to perform one point subtree crossover using python ast module.

Here's the code
node_to_be_replaced is a tuple 0th element contains the node which was selected from parent one randomly and 1st element contains the index of that node in that list.

collector_two is a list of references from the second parent.

`def modify_node_using_parent(self, node_to_be_replaced, parent_two):
        size = len(self.collector_two.statements)
        if(self.get_the_node_type(node_to_be_replaced[0]) == "Assign") or 
(self.get_the_node_type(node_to_be_replaced[0]) == "AnnAssign") or (self.get_the_node_type(node_to_be_replaced[0]) == "AugAssign"):
          j = random.randint(0, size - 1)
          node_to_be_replaced_with = self.collector_two.statements[j] 
          self.collector_one.all_changable_nodes[node_to_be_replaced[1]] = node_to_be_replaced_with
          self.collector_two.statements[j] = node_to_be_replaced[0]`

Collector class is a class which traverses the tree and makes the list of the references of the same type of nodes like statements and expression etc.
Now I select a node from one parent and choose the same type of node from the other parent and finally, I swap those references from the list.
But when I convert those ASTs back to the source code then unparser class raises the AttributetypeError.

**any help would be appreciated**

Comment: Could you provide more information? What have you tried and why it doesn't work? How is your tree representation?